# Best way to watch multiple IRC channels in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, irc, azure-appservice

I am attempting to connect my application to multiple IRC channels to read incoming chat messages and send them to my users.  New channels may be added or existing channels may be removed at any time during the day and the application must pick up on this in near real-time.  I am currently using Microsoft Azure for my infrastructure and am using App Services for client-facing compute and Azure Functions on the App Service plan for background tasks (Not the consumption billing model).

My current implementation is in C#/.NET Core 3.1 and uses a `TcpClient` over an `SslStream` to watch each channel.  I then use a `StreamReader` and `await reader.ReadLineAsync()` to watch for new messages. The problem I am running into is that neither App Services or Azure Functions seems to be an appropriate place to host a watcher like this.

At first, I tried hosting it in the Azure Function app as this clearly seems like a task for a background worker, however Azure Functions inherently want to be triggered by a specific event, run some code, and then end.  In my implementation, the call to `await reader.ReadLineAsync()` halts processing until a message is received.  In other words, the call running the watcher needs to run in perpetuity, which seems to go against the grain of an Azure Function.  In my attempt, the Azure Function service eventually crashes, the host unloads, all functions on the service cease and then restart a few minutes later when the host reloads.  I am unable to find any way to tell what is causing the crash. This is clearly not the solution I want.  If I could find an `IrcMessageTrigger` Azure Function trigger, this would probably be the best option.

Theoretically, I could host the watcher in my App Service, however when I scale out I would run into a problem due to having multiple servers connecting to each channel at once.  New messages would be sent to each server and my users would receive duplicates.   I could probably deal with this, but the solution would probably be hacky and I feel like the real solution would be to architect it better in the first place.

Anyone have an idea?  I am open to changing the code or using a different Azure service (assuming it isn't too expensive) but I will be sticking with C# and .NET Core on Azure infrastructure for this project.

Below is a part of my watcher code to provide some context.

```
while (client.Connected)
{
    //This line will halt execution until a message is received
    var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

    if (data == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var dataArray = data.Split(' ');

    if (dataArray[0] == "PING")
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync("PONG");
        await writer.FlushAsync();

        continue;
    }

    if (dataArray.Length > 1)
    {

        switch (dataArray[1])
        {
            case "PRIVMSG":
                HandlePrivateMessage(data, dataArray);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are preliminary, but it appears that the correct approach is to use Azure WebJobs running continuously to accomplish what I am trying to achieve.  I did not consider WebJobs initially because they are older technology than Azure Functions and essentially do the same work at a lower level of abstraction. In this case, however, WebJobs appear to handle a use case that Functions are not intended to support.

To learn more about WebJobs (including continuous WebJobs) and what they are capable of, see the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#webjob-types)